# Reporting Services calculating sub totals using custom code issue

Tags: c#, vb.net, reporting-services

I am using custom code to calculate sub totals.  The sub totals are running totals going downward.

The below custom code is working great if I run the report for 1 period.

**Custom Code**

```
Public Shared Dim SortCodeTotal as Decimal

Public Shared Function Initialize()
    SortCodeTotal = 0
End Function

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal b as Decimal) as Decimal
   SortCodeTotal  = SortCodeTotal + b
   return b
End Function

Public Function DisplayTotal(ByVal b as Decimal) as Decimal
    Dim ret as Decimal = 0
    ret = SortCodeTotal + b
    SortCodeTotal = ret
    return ret
End Function
```

**Detail Line** Contain this expression

```
=Code.AddTotal(Sum(Fields!Activity_Amt.Value))
```

**Summary Total** contains this expression

```
=Code.DisplayTotal(0)
```

The report is using a matrix.  The custom code does not correctly when running with more then 1 period.  How to I change the custom code to work on all periods in a matrix.

The sub totals work like a running total.

Example

```
Detail 1     $50
Detail 1     $50
Sub Total   **$100**

Detail 2     $40
Detail 2     $40
Sub Total   **$180**

Detail 3     -$50
Detail 3     $50
Sub Total   **$180**

Detail 4    $20
Detail 4    $50
Sub Total   **$250**
```

The totaling is happening on the **previous sub total** + the **next detail lines**

[Click this to see how the report looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCvec.png)

[Click this to review the report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCZWw.png)

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your matrix specifying the cell from you are invoking the custom code. Also expected result could be useful.

Comment: you could use RunningValue() function in ssrs report.

Comment: The runningValue() does not seem to work.  I could be using it wrong.

Comment: i have attached a picture of the report

Comment: If I understand your issue correctly, you have a column group by `Period_Nbr` and the custom code just works for the first generated column, is it ok?

Comment: That is correct.  The custom code is only working with 1 column Period_Nbr.  If I run the report with more then 1 period column the custom code no longer works.  I believe I have to create some type custom code that is a collection or array.  No sure what to do.

Comment: Could you explain how it should work and what you mean by custom code no longer works if there is more than one period? What should be the result? I think the problem is that you are not reseting the variable when period group changes.

Comment: Please click on the first image.  The image will show how the columns should calculate.

Comment: If you don't add details it is complicated to guess what the problem is, what is the value you are passing to both custom functions? In your first image cannot be seen how the additional columns should look, the total should be cumulative for every column as for rows?

Comment: I have added more information to the post.  Please review.  New images have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your issue is related to the way SSRS process the matrix. Each entire row is evaluated before pass to the next one, so your cumulative total is being calculated horizontally while you need the running total vertically for each column.

The below custom function uses a `Collection` to store the total of each period for each row.

```
Public Shared dict As New Collection

Public Function AddTotal(ByVal value as Double, ByVal period As String) As Object

    Dim subtotal As Double

    If not dict.Contains(period) Then
        dict.Add(value, period)
        subtotal = dict.Item(period)  
        Return subtotal
    End If
    subtotal = dict.Item(period) + value
    dict.Remove(period)
    dict.Add(subtotal,period)
    Return dict.Item(period)

End Function
```

To call this function use:

```
=Code.AddTotal(sum(Fields!Activity_Amount.Value),Cstr(Fields!Period.Value))
```

I think there is no need for additional functions, since this returns the cumulative total in each evaluation as long as you use it in the correct scope, inside the period group, outside the details group and inside the `Sort Code` group.

[image]

It produces:

[image]

In my dataset `Period` field has the values 1 and 2

Comment: Awesome!!!!!!!  Thanks alejandro...  This works great !!!!   You have made my day.  Thanks for all you time.  I am a happy man.

Comment: @RobertThompson, You are welcome. If my answer helped you, you can marked it as the correct answer. [How to select an answer as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hey alejandro,  I am having problems with the first summary total.  After the first summary total everything is working.

Comment: Here's what I found.  The custom code needs a way to reset the collection.  The reason why is because each time I run the report the Activity Amount doubles on the summary total.

Comment: @RobertThompson, It works for me, aren't you calling the function twice?

Comment: I am good now.  I add the following code.  The problem only happen when export to excel.   **Public Shared Function Initialize()
    dict.clear()
End Function**     and **Public Function GetGrandTotal(ByVal b as Decimal) as Decimal
   dict.clear()
    Return b
End Function**

Comment: @RobertThompson, I am glad you managed to solve your specific problem.